# How to implement`list_filter(array, elem -> elem IN <column in other table>)`

Tags: duckdb

I have a table containing "good" values:

`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE GOOD AS SELECT [2, 3] as good;`

I want to filter a list of elements, only keeping ones that are in that list.

Basically, I want the same output as `SELECT list_filter([1,2,3,4], elem -> elem IN (2,3));`, except I have several hundred items in the goodlist (not just 2 and 3), so it is being slow. So I figured that if I put the test elements in a separate table then duckdb could use a hash join under the hood and it would be fast. If there is another better way to solve this root slowness problem way, then that would count as a solution too!

`list_intersect()` will not work for me because I actually need to compare the normalized version of the input to see if it's in the goodlist. e.g. my filter condition lambda is semantically
`elem -> normalize(elem) IN (SELECT good FROM GOOD))`

I have tried:

`SELECT list_filter([1,2,3,4], elem -> elem IN (SELECT good FROM GOOD));`

but that yields

```
Invalid Input Error: Subqueries are not supported in lambda expressions!
```

I tried converting this to a CTE:

`WITH g as (SELECT good from GOOD) SELECT list_filter([1,2,3,4], elem -> elem IN g.good;`

but no dice:

```
Parser Error: syntax error at or near "g"
LINE 1: ...list_filter([1,2,3,4], elem -> elem IN g.good;
```

This is more out of scope, but eventually I want to be able to convert this to an ibis expression so I can execute this from python, but first I want to verify that this is even possible from within duckdb before I add the wrapper layer.

Comment: Does using `list_intersect` help here, given you are checking for existence between two lists?

Comment: good thought. I edited my question to explain why that won't quite work.

Comment: It may be possible to use `list_transform` to apply the normalization before using `list_intersect`. Something like `list_intersect(list_transform(l.my_lists, elem -> normalize(elem)), g.good)`.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- fake your good table
create table good as select range as g from range(1,10);
```

You need to either `list()` your good, or `unnest` the haystack. A solution using a join, i.e. `LATERAL` won't work without a distinct.

Variant a unnesting the input list

```sql
WITH the_list AS (
  SELECT unnest([1,2,3,11,12,13]) AS v
)
SELECT list(g)
FROM the_list JOIN good ON g = v;
```

Variant b, listing the good:

The idea is to collect everything in `good`. I guess it should work well enough with a couple of hundred entries.

Solution without intersect

```sql
with g as (select list(g) as v from good) 
select list_filter([1,2,3,11,12,13], e -> list_contains(g.v, e)) 
from g;
```

Solution with intersect

```sql
with g as (select list(g) as v from good) 
select list_intersect([1,2,3,11,12,13], g.v) 
from g;
```